# Illustrator Import to After Effects

Tags: after-effects

I have an illustrator file with vector paths made up of all strokes. When imported into AE and converted to shape layers, all the strokes turn into filled shapes. I want them to stay as strokes so I can utilize Trim paths. Any Idea about this?

Answer (score 0):

I've had success with

import composition > layer size

Double click comp

Highlight all > Create > Create Shapes from vector layer

Delete the .Ai layers

Tutorial here:

Answer (score 0):

The overlord plugin would help greatly with this workflow:

https://www.battleaxe.co/overlord

It lets you move vectors back and forth between Illustrator and After Effects.